# How does the timeline in "Altered Carbon: Resleeved" relate to the TV series timeline?

Tags: altered-carbon

I've just finally watched [*Altered Carbon: Resleeved*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9310328/) and I'm wondering how the show actually fits into the timeline of the [TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon_(TV_series)) universe (or potentially the [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon) universe if that fits better).

It seems to me that it can't follow the TV series, because Reileen is real-dead (stack death) after the first season.  (In fact Reileen is real-dead after the first book, *Altered Carbon*, too.)

*Resleeved* is close to the TV series in that it has Reileen as Kovacs' sister (she is just another Meth in the novel), and the Envoys are implied to be anti-Protectorate.  There is a hint in a comment that Reileen makes that in this continuity she also betrayed the Envoys to the Protectorate.  So it's obviously related to the TV series' continuity, and it has to take place *after* CTAC wiped out the Envoys but before the events of the TV series.

But in this time period, the TV show is clear that Kovacs was basically on ice from the time he was captured, shortly after the Envoys were destroyed.  (Notably, from the flashbacks of the first season, Kovacs had not been on the run long and was never able to get off of Harlan's World.)

If Reileen is still just a merc working for the Protectorate, and not yet a Meth, then it suggests this must take place very shortly after the Envoys were destroyed. However the backstory of *Resleeved* has Kovacs on Latimer trying to buy himself out of trouble with the Yakuza clans on Harlan's World, which conflicts with him not being able to leave Harlan's World before his capture.  It also doesn't match the TV series where after his capture he was only ever re-sleeved to solve someone else's problem, whereas in *Resleeved* Kovacs is working for his own ends.

Did they retcon Kovacs' story in the period immediately after the destruction of the Envoys (but before his capture by Jaeger) to allow more scope for him to go off-world, or is this intended to be somewhat later (how much?) after his capture (probably without a two-hundred-year timeout on ice) but with Kovacs granted more autonomy than he had in the TV series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Screenrant:

> During a VR briefing Hideki reveals that it has been one year since Takeshi's sister, Reileen Kawahara, was (supposedly) killed alongside Quellcrist Falconer in the attack on Stronghold. This means that **Altered Carbon: Resleeved is set in 2131,** during Takeshi's time working as a mercenary. The anime takes place three years before CTAC finally caught up to Takeshi and put his stack on ice. **That's 253 years before the main events of Altered Carbon season 1, and 283 years before the events of Altered Carbon season 2.**
>
> <sub><sup>[When Altered Carbon: Resleeved Is Set in the Timeline](https://screenrant.com/altered-carbon-resleeved-timeline-setting-prequel/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ah, thank you; I missed that.  So they retconned what happened to him in those 4 years and invented the Yakuza problem.